# Set limit: :infinity as a default elixir

Tags: io, elixir

I'm pretty talented at typing:

`IO.inspect(something, label: something_else, limit: :infinity)`

Now I'm wondering if there's a way via configuration to always do the `limit: :infinity` part w/o having to type it in every time.

Is this even a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the default inspect behaviour by setting [`Inspect.Opts.default_inspect_fun/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13/Inspect.Opts.html#default_inspect_fun/1):

```elixir
previous_inspect = Inspect.Opts.default_inspect_fun()

Inspect.Opts.default_inspect_fun(fn term, opts ->
  previous_inspect.(term, %Inspect.Opts{opts | limit: :infinity})
end)
```

Before:

```elixir
iex(1)> Enum.map(1..100, & &1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, ...]
```

After:

```elixir
iex(4)> Enum.map(1..100, & &1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

However, this comes with caveats in the docs:

> Set this option with care as it will change how all values   in the
> system are inspected. The main use of this functionality   is to
> provide an entry point to filter inspected values,   in order for
> entities to comply with rules and legislations   on data security and
> data privacy.

As you can see, it has overridden how iex displays the results, which also uses the `Inspect` protocol, in addition to the options passed to `IO.inspect`:

```elixir
iex(5)> Enum.map(1..100, & &1) |> IO.inspect(limit: 50)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82,
 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

---

If you only want to configure iex, not the entire [Inspect](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.html) protocol, you can put this in your [`.iex.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) file:

```elixir
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity])
```